# Ghostscript Pdf printing to network printer issues with formatting

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ghostscript

I use Windows 7 64 bit. I have a .net application and I am trying to print a PDF to a network printer using the below code:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
With startInfo
    .Arguments = String.Format("-dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNoCancel -dQUIET -q -dNumCopies={0} -sPAPERSIZE={1} -dPDFFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile=""\\spool\{2}"" ""{3}"" ", numberOfCopies, _PaperSize, _PrinterName, _PdfFileName)
    .FileName = ghostScriptPath '"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin64.exe"
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
End With
gs = Process.Start(startInfo)
```

The Pdf I am printing is editable pdf and has text with italic formatting. However, the italic formatting is not applied in the printed output.

Kindly let me know how this can be resolved.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the italic formatting' ? There is no 'italic formatting' (generally) in PDF, you just use an italic font. At a guess I would suggest that the font the PDF file is using is not embedded, and that the Ghostscript substitute font is not italic. I'd need to see the PDF file to be sure. As to 'resolving' it, embed the font in the PDF file.

Comment: PDf file is not created by me. When I open the pdf in Acrobat reader and print then it prints with correct italic font. If I use GS it prints as regular font (not italic)

Comment: So Acrobat (probably) uses a different substitute font, assuming that's the problem. Open the file in Acrobat, Go to File->Properties, select the 'Fonts' tab, look at each entry where it says 'Actual Font'. I'm guessing you'll find that the actual font used is not the same as the font name, showing that it has been substituted. You have a number of solutions, the proper way to fix this is to embed the fonts, then it will look correct everywhere. Secondly you can add a copy of the font to Ghostscript's installed fonts, finally you can define a different substitute font.